# How to make complex Model for my Flutter Dart Project?

Tags: flutter, dart, model

I need to create a dart Model class for this complex json .Please any one help

```
{
    "status": "1",
    "list": {
        "4": [
            {
                "id": "1289",
                "t": "Mutton biriyani",
                "p": "21",
                "i": "1289_5305.jpg",
                "v": "0"
            },
            {
                "id": "1288",
                "t": "Chicken biriyani",
                "p": "14",
                "i": "1288_5339.jpg",
                "v": "0"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

can any one help

Answer (score 0):

you can create modal of every json using this website [json-to-dart](https://javiercbk.github.io/json_to_dart/).
and after making some changes the modal for your jsong would be something like this

```
    class Modal {
      String? status;
      List<FoodList>? foodList;

      Modal({this.status, this.foodList});

      Modal.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        status = json['status'];
        if (json['list']["4"] != null) {
          foodList = <FoodList>[];
          json['list']["4"].forEach((v) {
            foodList!.add(new FoodList.fromJson(v));
          });
        }
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['status'] = this.status;
        if (this.foodList != null) {
          data['list']["4"] = this.foodList!.map((v) => v.toJson()).toList();
        }
        return data;
      }
    }

    class FoodList {
      String? id;
      String? t;
      String? p;
      String? i;
      String? v;

      FoodList({this.id, this.t, this.p, this.i, this.v});

      FoodList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
        id = json['id'];
        t = json['t'];
        p = json['p'];
        i = json['i'];
        v = json['v'];
      }

      Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
        final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
        data['id'] = this.id;
        data['t'] = this.t;
        data['p'] = this.p;
        data['i'] = this.i;
        data['v'] = this.v;
        return data;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example of a Dart Model class that could be used to parse the JSON you provided

```
class Model {
  final String status;
  final List list;

  Model({this.status, this.list});

  factory Model.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
   return Model(
   status: json['status'],
   list: json['list'],
 );
```

}
}

And you can use it like this

```
final jsonString = '{ "status": "1", "list": { "4": [ { "id": "1289", "t": "Mutton biriyani", "p": "21", "i": "1289_5305.jpg", "v": "0" }, { "id": "1288", "t": "Chicken biriyani", "p": "14", "i": "1288_5339.jpg", "v": "0" } ] } }';
```

final jsonMap = jsonDecode(jsonString);
final data = Model.fromJson(jsonMap);

Note that the List class is a basic type in dart, so it is not suitable for your json structure. In this case, you need to define a custom class for the "list" field.

Answer (score 0):

```
class FoodList {
  String status;
  Map<String, List<Food>> list;

  FoodList({this.status, this.list});

  factory FoodList.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    var list = json['list'] as Map;
    var foodList = list.map((key, value) {
      return MapEntry(key, (value as List).map((e) => Food.fromJson(e)).toList());
    });
    return FoodList(status: json['status'], list: foodList);
  }
}

class Food {
  String id;
  String title;
  String price;
  String image;
  String v;

  Food({this.id, this.title, this.price, this.image, this.v});

  factory Food.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Food(
        id: json['id'],
        title: json['t'],
        price: json['p'],
        image: json['i'],
        v: json['v']);
  }
}
```